# In Brownian motion, how does the absolute value of a particle's distance from the center scale with respect to number of iterations?

Tags: binomial-distribution, stochastic-processes

The mean distance is probably zero due to averaging out. But what about the mean of the absolute distance?

Comment: Since distances cannot be negative, it's difficult to see how they could "average out" to zero!

Answer (score 2):

You would be looking at a [half-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution), whose expectation is $\sigma \sqrt{2/\pi}$, if the underlying normal random variable has variance $\sigma^2$. Furthermore, the variance in Brownian motion is commensurate with time.